# R skips readline in loop

Tags: r, loops, readline

I'm trying to include a readline command in a for loop which is followed by other code. Using the code below I would expect R to ask for input three times, however I only get the opportunity to give a response twice as the code after the loop is considered one of the responses, which is not what I want or expected. I tried including a while loop to 'force' R to stop executing until it got a response from the user, but this does not seem to work. Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

```
response <- rep(NA,3)
for(i in 1:3) {
    while(is.na(response[i])) {response[i] <- readline("Give me a number: ") } # Ask for response
}
response
```

Comment: On my machine (R 3.1.0 on Win64) this works as you expect.

Comment: you answered your own question "I only get the opportunity to give a response twice as the code after the loop is considered one of the responses"

Comment: I've tried running this in R3.1.1 Win64, and it gives the same issue. The code below the loop is considered on of the responses. Any suggestions to prevent this from happening would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the readline statement and following statements are wrapped in curly brackets, the statements are executed in order. The below code works as expected.

```
{
  for(i in 1:3) { response[i] <- readline("Give me a number: ") }
  response
}
```